# mercurial discard all added files prior to a commit

Tags: mercurial

Just made the mistake of using `addremove` to try and remove some files that were deleted without using `hg remove`

Now have hundreds of files that are going to be added on the next commit

Is there anyway I can quickly remove all these added files without having to resort to a bash script or even worse `hg removing` or `forgetting` each file manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to just use internal `hg`commands, you can do the following:

```
hg forget "set:added()"
```

Which will forget any file that's marked as "added" in the working directory.  It makes use of the rather powerful [filesets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/filesets) feature of Mercurial.

There are additional filters you can use when specifying files, which allows you to easily fix other mistakes.  For example, easily re-add removed files but nothing else `hg add "set:removed()"`.  The functionality is similar to (tho' thankfully simpler than) mercurial [revsets](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets), and can be studied with:

```
hg help filesets
```

Comment: Didn't know about this. I have to give it a look sometimes. thanks !

Comment: Mercurial is a great tool, but some of its features are very well hidden unless you look in just the right place :)

Answer (score 3):

You do it quite easily on the command line using something along the lines of :

```
hg status --added --no-status | xargs hg forget
```

This should forget all files added since the last commit.

May I suggest to add the files you never want to add to a `.hgignore` file so this won't happen again ?

Comment: this is the approach i used after finding it on the mercurial tips tricks wiki but the other approach is appealing as it wouldn't be platform specific