# Rollback of the last command in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I just ran:

```
hg add .*
```

which matched all `../something` files and which was something I certainly did't want! What is the easiest way to undo this command?

Comment: It also actually skipped the Unix-hidden files I was trying to add!

Comment: I believe there's a `hg undo` that will remove the last commit but preserve the current file changes. This command will only work when the changeset is a draft, i.e. not after you've pushed to another repository.

Comment: @Patrick: that's not a standard command. The hg-multiundo extension I mention in my answer below provides an undo command, maybe you're thinking of that one?

Comment: @MartinGeisler: No, I was probably thinking of the rollback command, but perhaps that won't rollback a hg add.

Comment: @Patrick: no, not really, `rollback` will remove the last transaction from the repository. If the last transaction was a commmt, then `rollback` will incidentally affect the files scheduled for addition: it resets the dirstate to the state before the commit. So files that have been added after the last commit are no longer added and in that sense `hg rollback` will give the same result as `hg forget "set:added()"`.

Comment: But how did you manage to get `.*` to expand to that? On unix, `.*` is expanded by the shell, and you'd get all the dot files you intended, plus `..` (which triggers an error if you're already at the repository root). Did you pass a quoted `".*"` to hg?

Comment: @alexis, it wasn't quoted, but I was not in the repository root, I was in the `debian` subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what I was after, but made my life easier:

```
hg forget "set:added()"
```

this unmarks all the files that were added in the working repository. Obviously I also unmarked all the files that were added in preceding commands, so as I said this is not exactly what I was after...

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer that was given to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13510787/699305). You've got a duplicate!

Comment: Oops, I take that back! There's a better solution in your case, please see my answer. (Too late to help you, probably, but still...)

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a lot of uncommitted adds that you don't want to have to do over, you can use a mercurial fileset that only picks out pending adds *in subdirectories of the parent directory* (use this in the same directory where the erroneous command was issued):

```
hg forget "set:../** and added()"
```

Mercurial doesn't remember what path you used to refer to a file, so this will forget all files (under the parent directory) that were just added; but if you were deep in a large repository, it'll limit the scope of what you discard.

Your question is similar to [this recent question,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13510787/699305) but here we have an extra condition on the mistakenly added filenames.

Answer (score 1):

There is not built-in way to undo a `hg add` command.

The underlying problem is that `hg add` is manipulating the so-called "dirstate" (short for "working directory state". This is where pending changes such as files scheduled for commit is stored — and this storage is unversioned.

There is an extension, though, that can help you: [hg-multiundo](https://bitbucket.org/hstuart/hg-multiundo) will make backups of all files touched by Mercurial, including the dirstate. This means that you can use it to undo things like `hg add` or even `hg revert --no-backup`.